# [Query runs long time]Query same table in two different sessions in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have two queries below, usually each one will finish in few minutes, but yesterday one of them finish in time, but the other one ran up to 12 hours and did not even finish.

Session 1:

```
INSERT INTO TargetA WITH (TABLOCK)
    SELECT * 
    FROM Source (NOLOCK)
    --There are some joins here but TargetB is not in here
```

Session 2:

```
INSERT INTO TargetB WITH (TABLOCK)
    SELECT * 
    FROM Source (NOLOCK)
    --There are some joins here but TargetA is not in here
```

My questions is: if these two sessions are running at the same time, could that cause the query running long issue because of the same table being queried across two different sessions? Most time it is working fine, I think tables are indexed correctly, but sometimes the those two queries running for super long time on the server and cause the timeout.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Querying the same table in the select statements is not the cause of the timeout. It may be that the queries are resource intensive and compete with each other for memory, CPU, and disk IO when run concurrently. Perhaps some query/index tuning will help.

Comment: You need to look at the execution plans when this happens and any wait types encountered by the sessions.